# rollup, coffeescript issue when i dont use coffescript

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollup

Trying to add rollup to my babel codebase.

I'm getting an error related to coffee script when my code has no coffee script. I'm new to rollup so any help would be appreciated

Seems to be a library called `config` but I have no idea what might be using that.

```
[!] Error: Could not resolve 'coffee-script' from /Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/config/lib/config.js
Error: Could not resolve 'coffee-script' from /Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/config/lib/config.js
    at /Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/dist/rollup-plugin-node-resolve.cjs.js:85:23
    at /Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:50:13
    at processDirs (/Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:182:39)
    at ondir (/Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:197:13)
    at load (/Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:80:43)
    at onex (/Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:105:17)
    at /Users/terencechow/workspace/my-project/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:26:73
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:112:15)
```

// rollup.config.js

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json'
import yaml from 'rollup-plugin-yaml'
import coffee from 'rollup-plugin-coffee-script'

export default {
  input: 'server/app.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [
    json(),
    yaml(),
    resolve({ extensions: [ '.js', '.json', .yaml', '.yml' ] }),
    commonjs({ extensions: [ '.js', '.json', '.yaml', '.yml' ] }),
    babel()
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me:

`npm i -D coffee-script` or `yarn add -D coffee-script`